# Convert rows to columns without using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i convert this rows :

```
id id_name flag tag_name tag_type tag_value
1   1       163   XO       c          10
1   1       163   X1       c           0
1   1       163   AM       c           5
```

to this one row :

```
1   1      163      XO:c:10 X1:c:0 AM:c:5
```

Without using pivot ??

Comment: I assume there are different values for id, id_name and flag in your table?

Comment: Yes there are a lot of different id and id_name and flag.

Comment: juergen , in mssql please

Comment: Why don't you want to use pivot?

Comment: This is probably doable with a Cursor and temporary tables. But why would you want to put yourself through that pain? Pivot has been supported since SQL Server 2005

Comment: pivot doesnt works for me

Comment: I need to find solution without pivot .

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to do the equivalent of a `group_concat`, rather than a `pivot`

```
;with src as (select id, id_name, flag, tag_name+':'+tag_type+':'+CONVERT(varchar(5), tag_value) as tag from yourtable t1 )
SELECT distinct
      src.id, src.id_name, src.flag,
      tags = STUFF((
          SELECT ' ' + s.tag
          FROM src s
          WHERE s.id=src.id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM src
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to pivot your data like you've asked.  Generally it would be better to perform this sort of string building/manipulation within your application rather then on the database directly.  In this example Table2 can be swapped for a temporary table.

```
-- Create and Seed Table2
SELECT [id], [id_name], [flag], CAST(NULL as varchar(255)) AS [data]
INTO [Table2] FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [id], [id_name], [flag];

-- Declare variables to hold row
DECLARE @id int, @id_name int, @flag int,
        @tag_name varchar(2), @tag_type varchar(1), @tag_value int;

-- Declare the Cursor
DECLARE PivotCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [id], [id_name], [flag], [tag_name], [tag_type], [tag_value]
    FROM [Table1] ORDER BY [id], [id_name], [flag], [tag_name]
;

-- Use the cursor to update Table2
OPEN PivotCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM PivotCursor INTO @id, @id_name, @flag, @tag_name, @tag_type, @tag_value;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table2 SET
        [Data] = ISNULL([Data],'')+(CASE WHEN [Data] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' END)+@TagName+':'+@TagType+':'+CAST(@TagValue as varchar)
    WHERE [id] = @id AND [id_name] = @id_name AND [flag] = @flag;

    -- Get Next
    FETCH NEXT FROM PivotCursor INTO @id, @id_name, @flag, @tag_name, @tag_type, @tag_value;
END
CLOSE PivotCursor;
DEALLOCATE PivotCursor;
```

The resulting table looks like this:

```
id  id_name  flag   data
1   1        163    AM:c:5 X1:c:0 XO:c:10
```